# Extract exe resource and run it (in Visual Basic)

Tags: vb.net, resources

let's say i did add some exe file to the project's resources.
now if i want to run that file, i have to extract it from the resources as a new file and then i can run it
So please can someone help me with how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a resource as a stream from an assembly:

```
myAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("TheNameSpacename.NameOfYourFile")
```

Copying the stream to a file: already described here:

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file
```

(example is in C#, porting to VB.NET should be easy).

Running the file: use System.Diagnostics.Process.Start:

```
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx
```

Comment: Thanks but can u discrip what "TheNameSpacename" is ?

Comment: Dim appStream As Stream = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Me.Resources.GetHTMLsource.exe")

        Dim inStream As New StreamReader(appStream)

        Dim encoding As New System.Text.ASCIIEncoding

        Dim bytes = encoding.GetBytes(inStream.ReadToEnd)

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllBytes("GetHTMLsource.exe", bytes, False)

this is what i wirte but the "appstream" is always NULL

Comment: TheNameSpace must be the default namespace of your assembly. Look here http://www.jelovic.com/articles/resources_in_visual_studio.htm for an explanation. If you have to analyse an existing assembly regarding its namespace, I suggest using .NET reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)