# access assets from monodroid class library

Tags: xamarin.android, assets

Is it possible to access files (with build action "AndroidAsset") from a monodroid class library in a monodroid application that references the class library ?

I have created an "Assets" folder in the class lib and added a text file with build action "AndroidAsset", but from the app I could not access it via Assets.Open("file.txt");

I was hoping that the Assets from the class lib and the main application could somehow be "merged"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - you a can't access the assets from a class lib - only from the main exe project.

This is similar to the situation with Java Android projects.

---

One route around this might be to use embedded resources instead - see the answer to this question I asked on xamarin's forums - http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/186/is-there-a-cross-platform-way-to-include-string-resources-from-class-library-projects - note that I haven't tried this yet

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to access files (with build action "AndroidAsset") from a monodroid class library in a monodroid application that references the class library ?

Yes. Just access them "as normal" via [Context.Assets.Open](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Res.AssetManager.Open%28System.String%29). There is only one source of assets in the application, so any component can access any and all assets, if they have access to an `AssetManager` instance.

*However*, that just takes what you're asking at face-value. Can a Library project use the `Context.Assets` property? Certainly, if you provide it a `Context` instance.

But can a Library project *provide* it's own assets for inclusion into the application? No.

> I have created an "Assets" folder in the class lib and added a text file with build action "AndroidAsset", but from the app I could not access it via Assets.Open("file.txt");

Library projects cannot provide assets that will be included in the larger application. Java doesn't support this either, afaik.

Answer (score 0):

### Things to remember

1  Build Action is **AndroidAsset** (Properties)

2  Copy to output directory **Do not copy** (Properties)

3  Add the file to the **Assets** folder

```
var destinationPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "yourfilename.txt");
            using (Stream source = Assets.Open("yourfilename.txt"))
            using (var dest = System.IO.File.Create (destinationPath)) {
                source.CopyTo (dest);
            }
```

Sometimes this will still fail, monodroid bug.  The best thing to do is check to see if the files were included correctly.

```
Load up Eclipse, in the device browser, you should see your simulator.  
Go to the directory data/app/    download the file yourappname.apk
This is just a zip file, so change the extension to .zip and open the
zip archive. And goto the folder /assets and see if the file you are trying 
to load is in there.
```

Also if you try to grab a file off a physical device your testing on, some allow it and other don't. This is easiest to test on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to access the Assets files from a library:

```
var sourcePath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
//var files = Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath);
var filePath = Path.Combine(sourcePath, "MyAssetFile.bin");
var content = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
```