# Download a file from System.Io.Stream class C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, download, microsoft-graph-api, filestream

I am trying to download a file from my onedrive using the microsoft graph api. I have managed to get to the point where i can retrieve the item from the GraphServiceClient. However, once i get the file using `/me/Drive/Items/{itemid}/Content` it returns to me a `System.IO.Stream` object.

How do i use this `System.IO.Stream` object to download the file?

Here is the code i have now for getting the file (for security purposes i did not put the itemid in the sample code, but i can assure you it is correct.) :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> OneDriveDownload()
{
    string token = await GetAccessToken();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
    {
        // If there's no token in the session, redirect to Home
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    GraphServiceClient client = new GraphServiceClient(
        new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
            (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }));

    try
    {
        var stream = await client.Me.Drive.Items[ItemID].Content.Request().GetAsync();
        return View(stream);
    }
    catch (ServiceException ex)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home", new { message = "ERROR retrieving messages", debug = ex.Message });
    }
}
```

Additionally, i would like to create a button that can execute this download in the view.

Comment: Yea i looked at the before posting this. Doesn't really explain how to download the file to my pc...

Comment: Here's a one-liner, seeing as you're struggling to understand the duplicate : `using(var fs=File.OpenWrite(somePath)){stream.CopyTo(fs);}`

Comment: ...or in async world: `using(var fs=File.OpenWrite(somePath)){await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);}`

Comment: I used the solution from this other question to solve my problem. Thanks for your help everyone.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002834/saving-a-file-from-stream-to-disk-using-c-sharp

Comment: If it's the [top-voted and selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5002881/14357) to the question you linked to, think twice before using the code. It's dangerously broken. See the comments that I have left below to understand why.

Comment: Ok, what would you do instead that i can EASILY replace this with... this was the only method i managed to get actually working because its very simple.