# Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) or Position = 0

Tags: c#, .net, stream

When you need to reset a stream to beginning (e.g. `MemoryStream`) is it best practice to use

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

or

```
stream.Position = 0;
```

I've seen both work fine, but wondered if one was more correct than the other?

Comment: If it is to return the contents of the memory stream, ToArray works regardless of position

Comment: Answer: The one being most readable.

Comment: I personally prefer `stream.Position = 0;` but I have to agree with @jgauffin, just choose the most readable, both solutions work fine.

Answer (score 210, accepted):

Use `Position` when setting an absolute position and `Seek` when setting a relative position. Both are provided for convenience so you can choose one that fits the style and readability of your code. Accessing `Position` requires the stream be seekable so they're safely interchangeable.

Comment: I use the property even for relative positions: `stream.Position += 10;` seems pretty readable to me.

Comment: Is there a speed difference between using SeekOrigin.Begin and SeekOrigin.Current?

Comment: @gonzobrains ["Return Value: The new position within the stream, calculated by combining the initial reference point and the offset."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek.aspx). So the combining costs a little bit more than just setting the position directly. Practically it means nothing but nit-picking. )))

Answer (score 26):

You can look at the source code for both methods to find out:

- Position property 
  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,320
- Seek method 
  https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/memorystream.cs,482

The cost is almost identical (3 `if`s and some arithmetics). However, this is only true for jumping to absolute offsets like `Position = 0` and not relative offsets like `Position += 0`, in which case `Seek` seems slightly better.

However, you should keep in mind that we are talking about performance of a handful of integer arithmetics and `if` checks, that's like not even accurately measureable with benchmarking methods. Like others already pointed out, there is no significant/detectable difference.

Comment: MemoryStream does just arithmetics, because it is basically just a byte array. Is this true even for other seekable streams? I would be interested in how this works in FileStream. I suspect that even there, the difference is very small and it boils down to a single syscall setting the position, but I am not sure whether the current position is actually kept in memory. If it is not, getting it requires another syscall, unlike when using the Seek method.

Answer (score 7):

If you are working with files (eg: with the [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream) class) it seems [Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1651) is able to keep internal buffer (when possible) while [Position=0](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/filestream.cs,1238) will always discard it.

Comment: You are referencing .NET Framework sources. Does this hold for current .NET (.NET 8), too?

Comment: It seems to be different. `Position` setter defers the call to [_strategy.Position](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/FileStream.cs,500). `FileStream` use `BufferedFileStreamStrategy` as strategy and that one simply call [Seek(value, SeekOrigin.Begin)](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Strategies/BufferedFileStreamStrategy.cs,68). I would say buffer is preserved (to be tested).