# Advantage / Disadvantage MemoryStream.Position or MemoryStream.Seek

Tags: c#, memorystream

What is the advantage or disadvantage (or the difference) to use

`memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);`

instead of

`memoryStream.Position = 0`

Comment: Aren't these only the same if Begin is at the start of the stream?  Can't Begin be elsewhere?

This is a question I have re: MemoryStream: when does SeekOrigin.Begin change?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only advantage of `Position` is a shorter, more direct notation.

The advantage of `Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)` is that you also have `SeekOrigin.Current` and `SeekOrigin.End`.

But they are functionally the same, pick whatever you think is most readable.

Answer (score 1):

They're both the same internally and set the position of the stream. See [MSDN Stream.Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.stream.seek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).
`Position` is absolute while `Seek` provides a relative / offset position.

Whatever you prefer for readability.

```
Stream.Position += 50;
Stream.Seek(50, SeekOrigin.Current);
```

Answer (score 1):

Already answered here: [Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) or Position = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238929/stream-seek0-seekorigin-begin-or-position-0)

And I agree with gordy. That said, I don't see any real reason to use the method Seek in your scenario.