# How do you unzip a gz file in memory using GZipStream?

Tags: c#, compression, gzip, gzipstream

I'm probably doing something obviously stupid here. Please point it out!

I have some C# code that is pulling down a bunch of .gz files from SFTP (using the [SSH.NET Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/2016.0.0) - works great!). Each gz contains only a single .CSV file inside of them. I want to keep these files in memory without hitting disk (yes, I know, server memory management concerns exist - that's fine as these files are fairly small), decompress them in memory to extract the CSV file inside, and then return a collection of CSV files in a custom DTO (`FtpFile`).

My problem is that while my MemoryStream from the SFTP connection has data in it, either it doesn't ever seem to be populated in my GZipStream or the copy from the GZipStream to my output MemoryStream is failing. I have tried with the more traditional looping over Read with my own buffer but it had the same results as this code.

Aside from connection details (it connects successfully, so no worries there), here's all of my code:

**Logic**:

```
    public static List<FtpFile> Foo()
    {
        var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("example.com",
            "username",
            new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("username", "password"));
        using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
        {
            client.Connect();

            var searchResults = client.ListDirectory("/testdir")
                .Where(obj => obj.IsRegularFile
                              && obj.Name.ToLowerInvariant().StartsWith("test_")
                              && obj.Name.ToLowerInvariant().EndsWith(".gz"))
                .Take(2)
                .ToList();

            var fileResults = new List<FtpFile>();

            foreach (var file in searchResults)
            {
                var ftpFile = new FtpFile { FileName = file.Name, FileSize = file.Length };

                using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    client.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream); // Success! All is good here, so far. :)

                    using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                    {
                        using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                        {
                            gzStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                            byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray(); // No data. Sad panda. :'(
                            ftpFile.FileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputBytes);
                            fileResults.Add(ftpFile);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return fileResults;
        }
    }
```

**FtpFile** (just a simple DTO I'm populating):

```
public class FtpFile
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public long FileSize { get; set; }
    public string FileContents { get; set; }
}
```

---

***PSA*** If anybody comes and copies this code, be aware that this is NOT good code in that you could have some **serious** memory management problems with this code! It's best practice to instead stream it to disk, which is **not** being done in this code! My needs are very specific in that I have to have these files simultaneously in memory for what I'm building with them.

Comment: Is the Gzipped value valid? if you check the gzipped byte[], if it is a length of 10 and has the following sequence: 31,139,8,0,0,0,0,0,4,0 . It means it has not be gzipped properly.

Comment: @StfBln The GZipped value has a length of 1884 and starts with this sequence: 31,139,8,0,120,192,198,88. Also, this is coming from a third-party production system and we've had no problems working with these gz files manually in initial tests so far.

Comment: Does "client.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream)" rewinds the stream? else the fileStream needs to be rewinded using "Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are inserting data into the stream, make sure to seek back to its origin before un-gzipping it.

The following should fix your troubles:

```
            using (var fileStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                client.DownloadFile(file.FullName, fileStream); // Success! All is good here, so far. :)
                fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                using (var gzStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
                {
                    using (var outputStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        gzStream.CopyTo(outputStream);
                        byte[] outputBytes = outputStream.ToArray(); // No data. Sad panda. :'(
                        ftpFile.FileContents = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(outputBytes);
                        fileResults.Add(ftpFile);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you!! Is that the same as `fileStream.Position = 0;` or would the two be different?

Comment: @Jaxidian fileStream.Position = 0; should work as well. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238929/stream-seek0-seekorigin-begin-or-position-0 for more information.

Comment: Thanks again!! :-)