# StreamReader.ReadLine() doesn't consume the stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am starting a new web application project where a user can upload a `.csv` file so that I can process the file.

Currently I am able to let the user upload the file but when I try to use the `StreamReader` to read from the stream that generated from the file, it seems that the `StreamReader` cannot read from the stream properly.

By the way, for the upload file part I followed the Microsoft tutorial [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads)

Here is the code for the View.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Upload" asp-action="Upload">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
        <input type="file" name="files" >
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code for the Controller

The len, len2 and p are variables for debugging purposes.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null && file.Length > 0)
        {
            var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName(); //Note: May throw excepetion when temporary file exceeds 65535 per server
            var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create);
            await file.CopyToAsync(stream);//
            long len = stream.Length;// 412 bytes
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);//*
            int p = reader.Peek();//currently the next character is EoF
            var val = reader.ReadLine();
            long len2 = stream.Length;// 412 bytes
            bool end = reader.EndOfStream;// true

            //do some stuff here

            return RedirectToAction("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Upload_fail");//file not found
        }
    }
```

Any advice or help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try resetting the stream's position to 0 before you load it to the reader.  `stream.Position = 0`

Comment: @Kyle thanks for your advice, that actually work. So I am wondering what causes that position move to the end of the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When reading from a Stream, the current position is updated accordingly. As an example, imagine the following steps:

1. The position starts off at 0 (the beginning of the stream).
2. A single byte is read - This updates the position to 1.
3. Another byte is read - This updates the position to 2.

If there were only two bytes in the stream, the position is now considered to be [EOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) - It is no longer possible to read additional bytes, as they've already been read.

Relating this to your example, the call to `await file.CopyToAsync(stream)` advances the stream's position to EOF. As such, when you wrap a `StreamReader` around it, there's nothing left to read. The process is the same for writing - The `CopyToAsync` operation is advancing both the input and the output streams, resulting in both streams sitting at EOF once the operation completes.

To complicate things a little, Streams can be forward-only, meaning that it is not possible to go backwards once data has been read. As you are working with a `FileStream`, I think you are able to go back to the beginning, like so:

```
await file.CopyToAsync(stream);
stream.Position = 0;
```

You could also use `stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)`, as mentioned in this answer: [Stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) or Position = 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238929/stream-seek0-seekorigin-begin-or-position-0)

Comment: I'm facing the same issue and tried your solution including Seek(), but keep getting "Specified method is not supported" exception on .NET 7.

Comment: @AlexVPerl Not all `Stream`s support seeking, unfortunately.