# How to extract and run a file during installation

Tags: wix, wix3.5, dtf

I have created a Custom Action (DTF) with C#.
In that CA, I would like to extract a file from the msi (declared as Binary in wix) and run it with some arguments.
I haven't found any samples or help about that..
I have to execute a request on the msi, but I would like to have a sample. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DTF.chm has a sample how to update the Binary table. It's in "Working with MSI Databases" topic. And you can guess how to do the opposite operation. The code might look like this:

```
  using (var db = new Database("test.msi", DatabaseOpenMode.Direct))
  {
    using (var view = db.OpenView("SELECT `Data` FROM `Binary` WHERE `Name` = '{0}'", "testbinary"))
    {
      view.Execute();
      var rec = view.Fetch();

      var inStream = rec.GetStream("Data");
      if (inStream != null)
      {
        using (var file = File.OpenWrite("S:\\testfile.zip"))
        {
          CopyStream(inStream, file);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

The code of CopyStream method can be taken from [this answer of omnipresent Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file/411605#411605). Note that if you should do this from CA, you will reference the database object like `session.Database`, instead of creating it.