# Save StringBuilder to disk in .CSV format

Tags: asp.net, csv, save

I have a `StringBuilder` object which I have built with comma seperated values, which I would like to save as a `.csv` file.

I know how to stream the data as CSV, but how can I physically save the data as a `.csv` file, on the server?

Currently I stream the CSV like the following, where `sb` is `StringBuilder`:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=List.csv")
Response.ContentType = "text/csv"
Response.Write(sb.ToString)
Response.End()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already know how to create csv, so [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file) that shows how to save stream to file. As you're using ASP.NET just make sure you have the appropriate permissions to modify.

**Conclusion**

As you want to make the download available to user(instead of save it in the server) and csv is basically a text file check out [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/textfile.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's not different than writing a normal file. If you want to save the file to a folder in your application, you should use `Server.MapPath("~\MyCsvFiles")` to get the physical path of the file.

Comment: do you want to save to disk or send to the user for download? The above only is used to get the correct path to the server. Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/textfile.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version of IIS, ASPNET or NETWORK SERVICE needs write permissions on the server folder you are writing to; then just write the CSV file out with StreamWriter or your preferred method. If you really want an Excel file, then consider using EPPlus.