# Open byte array in Excel with COM Interop

Tags: c#, excel, resources, arrays, excel-interop

Well, in my project I need to use an excel file to read data from it (yes, a propper database would be better, but I cannot use one).

With Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel I open files like this:

```
Application.Workbooks.Open(FileName);
```

But I don't want to send that file along with the project `DLL`, because users are not meant to change this file.

So, I added it as a resource, and it became a byte array, with no path to disk.

```
byte[] ExcelFile = Properties.Resources.MyExcelFileResource;
```

Now, how do I load this byte array file with excel interop??? I want to open it properly as a real excel file, to work with it internally.

Comment: That's not possible, Excel has no idea how to look in your DLL to read a .NET resource.  It needs to be a file on disk.

Comment: Hey, the byte array is a file. It's me who will indicate it to excel.

Comment: Some people are saving this byte array to disk and then opening it. It's a solution, but not a good one.

Comment: See [Open Excel Workbook file Using Embedded Resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083473/open-excel-workbook-file-using-embedded-resource) and [Load excel file from resources/assembly in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16205252/load-excel-file-from-resources-assembly-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Also see a possible solution in [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9345609/1945631) to [c# using excel file from embedded resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9344726/c-sharp-using-excel-file-from-embedded-resource) that uses a third party package called "Excel Package Plus" which apparently supports loading from stream.