# C# streamreader to File

Tags: c#, .net, filestream, streamreader

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I save a stream to a file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

I want to write data from a readstream to a file in C#.
Something like the below:

```
StreamReader log = myexe.StandardOutput;

FileStream logfile = File.Create(LogFileName);

// write log to the logfile
```

Any suggestions please.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file

Comment: I do not understand it completely. myOtherObject.InputStream does not return StreamReader type. So how do implement it in my code ?

Comment: Then you need to edit your question to reflect your problem because your title states you want to save a streamreader to file, your example has a streamreader...

Comment: thanks @Jake1164 for pointing out, ill go through my questions and accept the answers I found correct.

Comment: Excellent!  You will find the little things you can do for the community will make a difference.

Comment: And I fixed the problemusing a StreamWriter instead of FileStream to write to the file.  
      StreamReader log = myexe.StandardOutput;
      StreamWriter logfile = new StreamWriter(LogFileName);  
      logfile.Write(log.ReadToEnd());