# .NET equivalent of Java FileChannel?

Tags: c#, tcp, nio, .net

I want to stream bytes directly from a TCP socket to a file on disk. In Java, it's possible to use NIO Channels, specifically `SocketChannel` and `FileChannel`. Quoting `FileChannel#transferFrom(...)`:

> This method is potentially much more efficient than a simple loop that
>   reads from the source channel and writes to this channel. Many
>   operating systems can transfer bytes directly from the source channel
>   into the filesystem cache without actually copying them.

Obviously I can just write the standard "copy loop" to read and write the bytes, and even take advantage of asynchronous I/O to minimize waiting. Will that be comparable to the platform native functionality that Java is taking advantage of, or is there another approach?

Comment: My guess is that a normal copy of the bytes would do well enough, the network should be the bottleneck not the coping from one stream to another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the data with a [`NetworkStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.aspx), then use the [`CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) extension method to write the data into a FileStream.

A manual approach, pre .NET4: [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

For sending, there is a [`Socket.SendFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx0a40c2.aspx) method that directly sends a file, utilizing the Win32 [`TransmitFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740565(v=vs.85).aspx) method. Unfortunately there is no corresponding `Socket.ReceiveFile` method or `ReceiveFile` Win32 API.

Comment: To make things even easier you can use the [TcpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx) as a wrapper around the Socket and NetworkStream (use the [GetStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.getstream.aspx) method).