# Extract/Move files from Embeddable resource

Tags: c#

I have a few exe's that I would like to store with my program upon being launched.

So far I have added an executable and 2 dll's as a resource. I have also set them to a "Embedded Resource" in there properties. There is one option where I could "Copy To Output Directory" However I would like to store them in another folder possibly

Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData

Instead of where my program is launched.

I have this so far from reading a few forums:

```
    Assembly _assembly;
    Stream _exemin;
    Stream _dllmin;
    Stream _dllmin2;

    _assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    _exemin = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LitecoinBN.minerd.exe");
    _dllmin = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LitecoinBN.libcurl-4.dll");
    _dllmin2 = _assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("LitecoinBN.pthreadGC2.dll");
```

However I'm not sure on how to extract these resources?

Answer (score 1):

Look into the `FileStream` and [Stream.CopyTo()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx)

Comment: Could I get an example of how this would be used?

Comment: There is an example on the msdn page I linked you to.  See the first CopyTo(stream) overload.

Answer (score 1):

[Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc4235zt.aspx) returns a [Stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) object.

**.Net 4.0 and above**

You can do whatever you want with this stream, like writing it to a file. If you are using .Net 4.0 or above, the stream class has a [CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932.aspx) method to allow you to copy a stream to another stream.

**Below 4.0**

If you are using a version of .Net below 4.0, you can see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411605/444610) by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) that has an example of copying a stream to a FileStream, ie: writing it to a file.