# How to create a webpage out of a httprequest received through GetResponse method

Tags: c#, httprequest

How can i get the `web` representation of a received `http-request`?
I recently asked a question on how i could circumvetnt a website censorship through a third `anonymizer website`.the result indicated i sniff the traffic and create the post `url` myself.
This stage is almost done.Now i need to get the page as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Winforms, you could go with the [`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) class.

> The **WebBrowser** control lets you host Web pages and other browser-enabled documents in your Windows Forms applications. You can use the **WebBrowser** control, for example, to provide integrated HTML-based user assistance or Web browsing capabilities in your application. Additionally, you can use the **WebBrowser** control to add your existing Web-based controls to your Windows Forms client applications.

(From MSDN)

---

You wish to save the response to disk. Ok, typically this is the sequence you'd take:

1. You make the HTTP request using the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class.
2. Get the response using the [`GetResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx) method. This will return an [`HttpWebResponse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.aspx) object.
3. Call [`GetResponseStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) on that response object, and then
4. [Write that stream to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file).

`<sidenote>` You should try and be a bit more clear in your question. I interpret the "web representation" of an HTTP request to be a "web page", as displayed in a browser. You never mentioned that you wanted to save the reply to disk.

Comment: Thanks,I dont plan on showing it on the form,Is it still useable for me?

Comment: @Hossein, What do you plan on doing then?  You make an HTTP request, you receive an HTTP response. The body of the response *is* the HTML you requested. That HTML is to be interpreted by a web browser. If you don't plan on parsing the code, or showing it in a browser, I don't know what you're trying to accomplish.