# How to use report.ExportToStream function in C#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, sendmail

I'm currently working in c#. I need to convert report file to pdf format and send it through mail. I wrote coding and its working. I use **`rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType)`** for conversion. But it takes long time. Can anyone please suggest me, how to use **`ExportToStream`** function,  so that i can avoid former one as i dont want the report file to be stored in my disk.
This is my code which is working

```
 rep1.Load(Server.MapPath("CrystalReport_ModbusNode.rpt"));
 rep1.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat,Server.MapPath("Modbus.pdf"));
```

I tried this:

```
rep1.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
rep1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Modbus.pdf"));
```

But if I use this, **Modbus.pdf** is still in `rpt` format.
`ExportToStream` id not doing any changes??
 How can I send mail, without exporting it to my disk. Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The ExportToStream function returns a Stream. You can then use this stream to write a file.
See this answer for details : [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)