# Why System.InvalidCastException in CrystalReport Export?

Tags: c#, wcf, crystal-reports

I am creating a WCF service which will create .pdf using Crystal Report and save the file in specific path in server. Why I am getting **System.InvalidCastException** exception in this line? Also I am getting this exception in every Export function.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = (MemoryStream)cryRpt.ExportToStream(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

Exception Details:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass' to
>   interface type
>   'CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ISCRReportSource'. This
>   operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component
>   for the interface with IID '{31E7715A-8AD0-4D1C-958E-C1BE0A6F2D0C}'
>   failed due to the following error: No such interface supported
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).'

[Exception Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMMzy.png)

Note: There is no problem with Crystal Report. When I use same code in a console application it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. My problem is solved by just updating the Crystal Report to Version 18.0.23. May be older version doesn't work well with WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Because it does not return a MemoryStream.

Take a look at [this link](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3322762) to get more information. They say that method returns an instance of FileStreamDeleteOnClose since some version of Crystal and it was a decision of the developers.

Take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14998750/how-to-use-report-exporttostream-function-in-c-sharp) to see how to approach it in another way.

EDIT:

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46556393/windows-form-application-error-with-crystal-report), the workaround was to downgrade Crystal Reports. Not nice...

In [SAP forums](https://answers.sap.com/questions/304272/upgrade-to-sp-21-unable-to-cast-to-interface-type.html), there is a discussion about it. It is said that, to avoid that, Microsoft Windows Update KB2999226 is a prerequisite for SP21 (among some details). Check your Crystal Reports version and check if it applies to you.

Comment: I said i got this exception in every Export method. In this ExportToDisk() too.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.