# S22.Imap save message attachment to local hard disk

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, imap

I need to store Message attachment into local hard drive.. Is there any work around for achieving this? I am using S22.Imap dll

```
using (ImapClient Client = new ImapClient("imap.gmail.com", 993,
            "xxxxxx@xxxxx.com", "xxxxxxxxxx", S22.Imap.AuthMethod.Login, true))
            {
                uint[] uids = Client.Search(
                    SearchCondition.From("test.account.rac@gmail.com").And(
                    SearchCondition.SentSince(new DateTime(2013, 5, 8))).And(
                    SearchCondition.SentBefore(new DateTime(2013, 5, 9)))
                );

                MailMessage[] messages = Client.GetMessages(uids,
                    (Bodypart part) =>
                    {
                        // We're only interested in attachments
                        if (part.Disposition.Type == ContentDispositionType.Attachment)
                        {
                            Int64 TwoMegabytes = (1024 * 1024 * 2);
                            if (part.Size > TwoMegabytes)
                            {
                                // Don't download this attachment
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                        // fetch MIME part and include it in the returned MailMessage instance
                        return true;
                    }
                );
                string attachment_name;
                if (messages[0].Attachments.Count > 0)
                {




                }
            }
```

There is no built-in method for saving these attachment to local drive. Moreover this can be achievable via S22.Mail.dll library but i can't find out this library. Does anyone can provide me solution?
Here is the link for S22.Mail source code https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Mail.

Answer (score 0):

There was/is some issues with the library that i tried to fix in [Pull #42](https://github.com/smiley22/S22.Imap/pull/42) (when writing this it have not yet been merged - you might want to pull that branch instead.)

Then iterate over `Message.Attachments` instead of the parts.
`Net.Mail.Attachment.ContentStream` will give you a stream you can copy to a file.
To check the size, use `ContentStream.Length`.

How the stream can be saved have been covered in depth in: [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

Comment: Hey Nikize. Thanks for the response. Unfortunately i can't test this out because i am not working on that specific project. Somehow i had used some other library for achieving this functionality. Thanks.