# How to use HTML input control to upload files

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I had HTML input control to upload file but the file returns empty.

```
<input type="file" class="upload"  runat="server" id="FUFile"/>

string tempVar = "~/res/Posts/" + FUFile.Value.ToString();
        FUFile.ResolveUrl(Server.MapPath(tempVar));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is posting from the fileupload properly. If you need to save the FUFile.PostedFile :

```
if (FUFile.PostedFile != null)
{
    string tempVar = "~/res/Posts/" + FUFile.Value.ToString();
    FUFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(tempVar));
}
```

**Here's how you can test it:**

In markup I have this:

```
<input type="file" class="upload"  runat="server" id="FUFile"/>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

In code I have this method:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FUFile.PostedFile != null)
    {
        string tempVar = "~/res/Posts/" + FUFile.Value.ToString();
        FUFile.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(tempVar));
    }
}
```

When I select a file and click the button, it uploads the file to ../res/Posts folder.

[image]

Comment: I had this error Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 1):

Just use a FileUpload control

```
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FUFile">
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="UploadButton" Text="Upload file" OnClick="UploadButton_Click"/>
```

You can then use `FUFile`'s properties (`FileContent` for a stream, `FileBytes` for the full content as an array of bytes, `PostedFile` for the `HttpPostedFile` object which has the `SaveAs` method) as you need.

For example, see this answer for saving the stream: [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file)

See a full example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload(v=vs.110).aspx