# How can I use readbyte function faster

Tags: c#, serial-port, binaryfiles

I'm using serialport in c# and my code is like this:

```
FileStream MyFile = new FileStream(strFileDestination, FileMode.Append);
BinaryWriter bwFile = new BinaryWriter(MyFile);
bwFile.Write(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
bwFile.Close();
MyFile.Close();
```

when I use

```
bwFile.Write(serialPort1.ReadByte());
```

instead of

```
bwFile.Write(serialPort1.ReadExisting());
```

, writing speed in file decreases from about 130 KB/s to 28 KB/s
and when I use

```
bwFile.Write((byte)serialPort1.ReadByte());
```

, writing speed decreases to 7 KB/s.
I want to know how Can I write in to file like the third command and have the speed 130 KB/s.

Comment: maybe do `serialPort1.ReadByte()` in a loop?

Comment: Yes. I use this command in a loop. the loop is like this: while Logger==true{/*the code I posted*/} and Logger is a variable that let my program to write in a file. by pressing a button logger changes to false

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you considered simply using a stream to write the data? I don't think you are actually using the extra features that BinaryWriter offers over Stream.Write.

Simply call the CopyTo() method

```
Stream destination = new FileStream(...)
MyFile.CopyTo(destination);
```

Which under the hood is calling the following code:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
int read;
while ((read = serialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) != 0)
{
    destination.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
```

Have a look at this post for further information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/411605/283787

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using simply Filestream. but the data in the file is not received completely. I mean somewhere in the file, some data are not the real data that the sender sends to my laptop. by the way, my laptop doesn't have any serial port and the device which sends to my laptop, is using a usb cable and I'm using virtual COM.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried using simple Filestream. but the data in the file is not received completely. I mean somewhere in the file, some data are not the real data that the sender sends to my laptop. by the way, my laptop doesn't have any serial port and the device which sends to my laptop, is using a usb cable and using virtual COM. anyway I couldn't use the code you write above. I got compile error Can you explain the code more please. (My English isn't well. sorry if I had mistake in sentences. and I didn't understand meaning of sentence"Which under the hood is calling the following code")

Comment: What is the compile error you get? For a full explanation have a look at the link I posted, there are more details there.

Comment: It worked. the problem was "Read" word. when I used SerialPort1.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)  it worked. (which SerialPort1 is the port name I defined in the code.) Thanks.

Comment: That's great to hear. If you could mark the answer as the solution that would be great. Thanks