# REST Server for uploading and downloading documents

Tags: android, file, rest, azure, server

I wrote an android application that part of it is to handle upload and download documents.  Currently I am using  the Microsoft Azure server to save the files on.

The  way I am currently doing  it is by turning  the files to a string  and saving it that way on the Azure server:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
FileInputStream fis;
try {
      fis = new FileInputStream(new File(Uridata.getPath()));
      byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
      int n;
      while (-1 != (n = fis.read(buf)))
             baos.write(buf, 0, n);
} catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] bbytes = baos.toByteArray();
item.setStringFile(Base64.encodeToString(bbytes, Base64.URL_SAFE));
item.setName(Uridata.getLastPathSegment());
```

where **item** is my class that saves the string  representation  and  the  name of the file and is being loaded to the Azure, **Uridata** is an Uri instance of the file chosen.

I have one main problem with this  solution and it is the limit  on the file size.
I am searching for a good server to use instead of the Azure (maybe a RESET one) and if there is a better way to save  files  of all kinds (pdf, word...).

I will also want in the future to use the same data in a web  interface

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start, you don't have to transform the file into a string, you can just save it as a file. You have the possibility of losing data by continuing to do that. See: [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c)

If you're looking for another service to save files, then you should look into Azure Blob Storage. It will allow you to upload as much data as you want to a storage service for arbitrary files. See for example:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/

Comment: I didn't know they have a blob storage. I thinks this could be very useful. Thanks!!