# Is there a library to resize an image

Tags: image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, resize, ffimageloading

I am currently using FFImageLoading package to do caching etc to show on the ui. I am unsure whether FFImageLoading have function to resize the image itself so i can save it and send over the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
var stream = await ImageService.Instance.LoadFile("someimage.png")
     .DownSample(width: 200)
     .AsPNGStreamAsync();
```

Comment: I can't find AsPNGStreamAsync and cannot await  as well

Comment: @LittleFunny: You must use `using FFImageLoading` at the top of your file.

Comment: The algorithm behind this function uses [`inSampleSize`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options#inSampleSize), which doesn't give you the exact size you asked for.

Comment: I'm using `CopyStream` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/411605/426227) for storing the result into a file.

Comment: @Daniel Luberda, how to get path from stream of new re-sized image? plz help