# SkiaSharp: rotate big picture multiple times without crashing the app because of memory management

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, memory-management, image-rotation, skiasharp

The goal is to be able to rotate an image taken by the camera app. My code is based on [this rotation](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Bitmaps/BitmapRotatorPage.xaml.cs#L35) and [this cropping algorithm](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/Bitmaps/PhotoCropperCanvasView.cs#L87). General infos can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/cropping). The problem occurs only if a big image (e.g. 2 MB) is used and the rotation is done multiple times (e.g. 70x). I'm using an Android tablet with 3 GB of RAM.

This is the place where my code crashes:

```
public void Rotate()
{
    double radians = Math.PI * this.rotationAngle / 180;
    float sine = (float)Math.Abs(Math.Sin(radians));
    float cosine = (float)Math.Abs(Math.Cos(radians));
    int originalWidth = this.originalBitmap.Width;
    int originalHeight = this.originalBitmap.Height;
    int rotatedWidth = (int)(cosine * originalWidth + sine * originalHeight);
    int rotatedHeight = (int)(cosine * originalHeight + sine * originalWidth);

    this.rotatedBitmap = new SKBitmap(rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);

    using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(this.rotatedBitmap))
    {
        canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);
        canvas.Translate(rotatedWidth / 2, rotatedHeight / 2);
        canvas.RotateDegrees((float)this.rotationAngle);
        canvas.Translate(-originalWidth / 2, -originalHeight / 2);
        canvas.DrawBitmap(originalBitmap, new SKPoint());
    }

    this.InvalidateSurface();
}
```

It crashes on the line with `new SKBitmap()` and the following message:

```
06-10 10:26:09.255 I/MonoDroid(19721): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
06-10 10:26:09.266 I/MonoDroid(19721): System.Exception: Unable to allocate pixels for the bitmap.
06-10 10:26:09.266 I/MonoDroid(19721):   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap..ctor (SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo info, System.Int32 rowBytes) [0x00023] in <0665b4d05b9e46c8a33bb731d6f5db83>:0 
06-10 10:26:09.266 I/MonoDroid(19721):   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap..ctor (SkiaSharp.SKImageInfo info) [0x00009] in <0665b4d05b9e46c8a33bb731d6f5db83>:0 
06-10 10:26:09.267 I/MonoDroid(19721):   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap..ctor (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, SkiaSharp.SKColorType colorType, SkiaSharp.SKAlphaType alphaType) [0x0000b] in <0665b4d05b9e46c8a33bb731d6f5db83>:0 
06-10 10:26:09.267 I/MonoDroid(19721):   at SkiaSharp.SKBitmap..ctor (System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, System.Boolean isOpaque) [0x00000] in <0665b4d05b9e46c8a33bb731d6f5db83>:0 
06-10 10:26:09.267 I/MonoDroid(19721):   at MyApp.PhotoCropperCanvasView.Rotate() [0x0009e] in C:\Users\some-user\Source\MyApp\PhotoCroppingCanvasView.cs:145
```

Things I tried:

1. Tried to `Dispose()` it:

   ```
   this.rotatedBitmap?.Dispose();
   this.rotatedBitmap = new SKBitmap(rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight);
   ```

   Here it crashes with the first dispose.
2. Use of `using`:

   ```
   using (SKBitmap newBitMap = new SKBitmap(rotatedWidth, rotatedHeight))
   {
       using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(newBitMap))
       {
           canvas.Clear(SKColors.White);
           canvas.Translate(rotatedWidth / 2, rotatedHeight / 2);
           canvas.RotateDegrees((float)this.picAngle);
           canvas.Translate(-originalWidth / 2, -originalHeight / 2);
           canvas.DrawBitmap(originalBitmap, new SKPoint());
       }

       newBitMap.CopyTo(this.rotatedBitmap);
   }

   this.InvalidateSurface();
   ```

   The same behavior occurs, where I can rotate the picture some times, but after a certain number (e.g. 70x) it crashes the app.

What can I do to have a better memory management? The only thing, which comes up to my mind is to use a minituarized/reduced image, but this will not stop the crash and only delay it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't receive any feedback I did what I could and this is the use of the reduced image. With this the app is more stable, but it doesn't 100% fix the issue.

The rotation algorithm stayed the same and for resizing the image I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46013148/426227) worked the best, because it reduces my image from ~2 MB to ~50 KB. Before I tried to use the sample implementation from Android, but I didn't get the efficiency like the `FFImageLoading` library does. With another resizing algorithm I also didn't get the smoothness in resizing. As for the sizes I used the current page width, which seems to be ok for portrait and landscape position.