# uploading image asp.net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

i am new to ASP.net COre and i would like to upload a file ( an image) and store it in a secific Folder. ihave been following this tuto ([File uploads in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-2.2)) but i dont know how to store it in a file it is just uploaded on the server
this is the html :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="UploadFiles" asp-action="Index">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the Controller

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

// full path to file in temp location
var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

foreach (var formFile in files)
{
    if (formFile.Length > 0)
    {
        using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
        }
    }
}

// process uploaded files
// Don't rely on or trust the FileName property without validation.

return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath});
}
```

and this is the class i am using

```
public interface IFormFile
{
string ContentType { get; }
string ContentDisposition { get; }
IHeaderDictionary Headers { get; }
long Length { get; }
string Name { get; }
string FileName { get; }
Stream OpenReadStream();
void CopyTo(Stream target);
Task CopyToAsync(Stream target, CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
}
```

i just need to store the image in a folder like :C:\Users\DESKTOP-1603\Desktop\GestionSyndic\GestionSyndic\src\WebApplication1\wwwroot\images\
 and change the name of the image thank you :D

Comment: We use `IFormFile.OpenReadStream()` and ImageSharp to validate it's an real image file. If you don't need this you can use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c

Comment: What you mean "store it **in a file** ? Did you mean, you want to store it in a specific folder in your app root ?

Comment: sorry i meant folder in my app root

Answer (score 17, accepted):

File upload in ASP.NET Core MVC in simple steps

1.Demo.cshtml View Code snippet

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="Index">
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
        <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
    </div>
</div>
```

2. DemoController

For showing demo i have created a Demo Controller which has 2 Action Methods in it one to handle Get Request and another to handle post request.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;

namespace WebApplication6.Controllers
{
    public class DemoController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IHostingEnvironment _environment;

        // Constructor
        public DemoController(IHostingEnvironment IHostingEnvironment)
        {
            _environment = IHostingEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(string name)
        {
            var newFileName = string.Empty;

            if (HttpContext.Request.Form.Files != null)
            {
                var fileName = string.Empty;
                string PathDB = string.Empty;

                var files = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    if (file.Length > 0)
                    {
                        //Getting FileName
                        fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

                        //Assigning Unique Filename (Guid)
                        var myUniqueFileName = Convert.ToString(Guid.NewGuid());

                        //Getting file Extension
                        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);

                        // concating  FileName + FileExtension
                        newFileName = myUniqueFileName + FileExtension;

                        // Combines two strings into a path.
                        fileName = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "demoImages") + $@"\{newFileName}";

                        // if you want to store path of folder in database
                        PathDB = "demoImages/" + newFileName;

                        using (FileStream fs = System.IO.File.Create(fileName))
                        {
                            file.CopyTo(fs);
                            fs.Flush();
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

> Snapshot while Debugging

[image: Snapshot while Debuggin]

> Location of folder where Images are stored

[image: Location of Folder where Images are Stored]

Comment: thanks for your esponse the problem i am facing now that i have added this code is that i can only subit the photo the model is no more submitted in the controller

Comment: the problem is i am not getting any error the model passed to the controller is just null here is the whole issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47319242/adding-photo-and-model?noredirect=1#comment81611148_47319242

Comment: This code isn't portable, backslash works in Windows only, always use Path.Combine():
`path += $@"\{newFileName}";   // wrong way`

Comment: This code works, only with the exception on updating `fileName`.

This line works for me on mac:
`fileName = Path.Combine(_environment.WebRootPath, "uploadImages") + $@"/{newFileName}";`

Answer (score 5):

You should inject `IHostingEnvironment` so you can get the web root (`wwwroot` by default) location.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        hostingEnvironment = environment;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadFiles(List<IFormFile> files)
    {
        long size = files.Sum(f => f.Length);

        // full path to file in temp location
        var filePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        foreach (var formFile in files)
        {
            var uploads = Path.Combine(hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "images");
            var fullPath = Path.Combine(uploads, GetUniqueFileName(formFile.FileName));
            formFile.CopyTo(new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create));

        }
        return Ok(new { count = files.Count, size, filePath });
    }
    private string GetUniqueFileName(string fileName)
    {
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
        return  Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fileName)
                  + "_" 
                  + Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Substring(0, 4) 
                  + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    }
}
```

This will save the files to the `images` directory in `wwwroot`.

Make sure that your form tag's `action` attribute is set to the `UploadFiles` action method of HomeController(`/Home/UploadFiles`)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-controller="Home"
                                                  asp-action="UploadFiles">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <p>Upload one or more files using this form:</p>
            <input type="file" name="files" multiple />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am not very certain why you want to return Ok result from this. You may probably return a redirect result to the listing page.

Answer (score 0):

Just used the accepted answer from @Saineshwar, but did a little bit refactoring as one extension method to make it easy to use IFromFile

```
public static string MakeFileUniqueName(this IFormFile formFile)
    {
        if (formFile.Length > 0)
        {
            string fileName =
                ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(formFile.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');

            // concatinating  FileName + FileExtension
            return Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(fileName);      
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```