# How to resolve my problem with upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

How can I upload my Image in asp.net core 2 without saved to database and after will show it in other View? Help, please.

Comment: I tried a lot to do this, but can't understand how it is work. May I not share my code? It was terrible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can do like this, :

> 1. Upload your image to a folder, not a database. Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47125439/uploading-image-asp-net-core)
> 2. Save the url of the image to database, basically it is not different from anything saving at database.
> 3. Give the url that you saved as source in your view.

for each steps you can find enough example in internet.

Comment: Ok, understood. Can I, for example, write image to session or not?

Comment: @СергейЧижик You don't need to write to session whole image; but if you want you can write the url after you saved image to a folder. but i don't think you need this better you get the url at your dataset. If it solved your problem can you please vote my answer and check as right answer.