# C# And Python file create setup file with library

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I have written a program. Thats include c# and python ı wrote the python from pycharm. After that ı created a ui from c# and ı called the python file from c#. And itis working fine.(Calling the .py file with cmd not ironpython). And now ı need to create the setup file thats include the c#, .py file and libraries.(cv2,os,..) . I will setup the program on another pc so ı need to setup python to that pc with environment variable set up to python. So the c# file can work like 'python main.py --param1 --param2'. How can ı create a setup file? Can anyone help me?

```
None

None

None
```

Comment: Learn to use Wix, InstallShield, or another installation / setup building tool.  That's way beyond the scope of a SO question, please read [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would download the python installer on the primary PC
2. create a stream of it ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c))
3. serialize [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/serialization/) it and store it in the app.

In your c# setup program

1. DeSerialize the python installer
2. run the installer. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands.)  from SO to execute
   commands from command prompt.

With C# libraries it can be similar approach and just use dotnet cli approach.