# save Response.OutputStream to folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a `HttpWebRequest` that is currently downloading the file  but I want to stop it downloading and save the file in a folder instead.

```
webRequest.Method = "GET";
webRequest.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=UTF-8";
using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
using (var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    if (webStream != null)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"test.pdf\"");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        webStream.CopyTo(Response.OutputStream);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the ContactType to `Response.ContentType = "application/x-download";` and adding `Response.TransmitFile` but the file still downloads.

Comment: You want to control the client action from the server? That is a browser setting. Did you mean you want to save the file to a folder on the server?

Comment: @mjw yes the file is automatically going to the download folder but I want to save it another folder on the server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: @mjw I am not using a StreamReader object