# Download stream to file

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, stream

I have a service which provides a stream. This stream should be written to a pdf-file.

I tried this method but it didn't work:

```
Using hcwHandler As IHealthCareWorkerServiceHandler = Container.CurrentContainer.Resolve(Of IHealthCareWorkerServiceHandler)()
  stream = hcwHandler.DownloadPrescription(New DownloadPrescriptionRequest With {
    .ProfessionCode = ucSelectProfession.ProfessionCode,
    .RizivNumber = ucSelectProfession.Nihdi,
    .Culture = language
  }).Result
End Using

Dim buffer As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(stream.ToString())

Using ms As New MemoryStream(buffer)
  'write to file
  Using file As New FileStream("prescription.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    ms.WriteTo(file)
  End Using
End Using
```

I have tried several other solutions as well, but none seemed to work.
I never get a file.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Put a breakpoint on this line `Dim file As New FileStream("prescription.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)` to ensure it is reached.

Comment: @preciousbetine the line is reached. So that is not the problem.

Comment: The file should be in your current folder. Where are you checking for the file?

Comment: @preciousbetine i cannot find the pdf file

Comment: @BartSchelkens 1) Just so you know, if the binary data of the PDF is processed as a string (e.g. with `stream.ToString()`) then it will be corrupted, and `Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes` will corrupt it even more. 2) Always give a full path to a file so that you know where it is.

Comment: @AndrewMorton And how can I download the pdf from the stream then? I have the file but it cannot be read.

Comment: @BartSchelkens The method is shown in [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411592/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I tried that method but it still doesn't work

Comment: @BartSchelkens What is the declaration of `stream`? Is it something which does not have a [.CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=netframework-4.8) method?

Comment: @AndrewMorton It has a copyto-method. It is declared as a System.IO.Stream

Comment: I have succeeded in downloading the file. But I want to display a message to the user that the file was downloaded and where.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the buffer (if there is data there) in a `Using` block without MemoryStream (like code below shows) and put a full absolute path  like `C:\Documents\PdfFolder\prescription.pdf`

```
Using saveFileDialog1 As New SaveFileDialog()
  saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\Documents"
  saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = True
  saveFileDialog1.Filter = "PDF files|*.pdf" ' change here for csv or xls
  saveFileDialog1.FileName = "yourDefaultfileName.pdf"

  If saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog <> Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
    If Len(saveFileDialog1.FileName.Length) > 0 Then
      Try
        Dim pdfPath As String = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(saveFileDialog1.FileName)

        Using file As New FileStream(pdfPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
          file.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)
        End Using

        MessageBox.Show("Saved in " & pdfPath)

      Catch
        MsgBox("Not a valid name file.")

      End Try
    End If
  End If
End Using
```

Comment: Usually when you download something in the browser, you can see that (in Google Chrome) at the bottom of the browser. How can I do that with the file I'm writing? I can find the file now, so it is being written.

Comment: And remember what @Andrew Morton says about file corruption. You need to treat stream directly/in another way

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj Perhaps you could convert the C# code from [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/411592/1115360) into VB.NET for the OP too, to make a complete answer ;)

Comment: Yes, done. I hope OP understand "yourStreamHere" in this case must to be a Stream (her stream) and not a path :).

Answer (score 0):

And here a VB.NET version of  [How do I save a stream to a file in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c)

```
Using fromWebFileStream As Stream = New StreamReader(yourStreamHere)
  Using localFileStream As FileStream = File.Create("C:\Documents\PathTo\File")
    'if you aren't at the begin of your stream uncomment this
    'fromWebFileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    fromWebFileStream.CopyTo(localFileStream)
  End Using
End Using
```

Comment: I get the exception : "specified method is not supported" on the fromWebFileStream.Seek

Comment: If you are at the start of your stream you can remove Seek method. I update the code, sorry I was distracted :)