# How to read audio files from Socket in C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, serversocket

I'm using socket programming to send live audio from my mobile to Desktop. I'm using C# language in Desktop side and JAVA in Mobile side. In desktop side I am receiving the audio that is send by mobile and is in the form of bytes. Can someone tell how I would convert these bytes that I have read from socket to audio file ? Below is, how I am reading bytes from socket

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Program started!!");
TcpClient client = null;
client = new TcpClient("192.168.0.113", 9999);
if (client.Connected)
{
    Console.Write("Client connected" );

    NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ns);
           
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    ns.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    Console.Write("Server>> " + sr.ReadLine());
    Console.Write("\n Audio Bytes are " );
    foreach (byte b in buffer )
    {
        if (b!=0)
        {
            Console.Write(b);
            //TODO Convert these bytes 
        }
    }
    Console.Read();
}
```

Below is the output:
[image]

Comment: "How to read audio files from Socket in C#?" You are already doing that. You are reading the audio file and you get bytes. What do you want to achieve besides reading audio files?

Comment: Files contain bytes. Write those bytes to a file with `File.WriteAllBytes` or using a FileStream

Comment: "Can someone tell how I would convert these bytes that I have read from socket to audio file?" Use a file stream and write them into a file?

Comment: `using var fileStream=File.Create(path); ns.CopyTo(fs);` This will copy the bytes from the network stream directly to the file stream.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I save a stream to a file in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c)

Comment: No, Because the the file is not playing the audio that i have sent from android device via socket.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to write the bytes to a file, you can create a [FileStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream?view=net-6.0) and copy the bytes from the network stream directly to the file stream with [CopyTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream.copyto?view=net-6.0):

```
var ns = client.GetStream();
using(var fileStream=File.Create(path))
{
    ns.CopyTo(fs);
}
```

If you want to keep the bytes in memory and process them you can use a [MemoryStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.memorystream?view=net-6.0). This class is a Stream wrapper over a byte[] buffer.

```
using(var ms=new MemoryStream(2048))
{
    ns.CopyTo(ms);
}

var theBuffer=ms.GetBuffer();
```

A `MemoryStream` grows by reallocating its internal buffer when it gets full. Specifying the capacity can eliminate or reduce reallocations, even if the initial capacity is a rough estimate.

Comment: ...which is no different than the duplicate I linked.

Comment: Which you did after I had already posted the comment.

Comment: 5 min ago (duplicate) versus 4 min ago (answer). And you could search for duplicates as well

Comment: Thanks, I've been doing this for quite a while now. New users often have trouble understanding why a specific duplicate answers their question. If someone is confused about files or buffers, posting a duplicate will confuse them even more

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I have coped the bytes to the file in the way you said above. But when I change the extension of file to .mp3, (because I want audio)  It says this file is not playable.

Comment: Are you sure the data is an actual MP3 file? MP3 is a compressed format and the image you posted has a *lot* of repeating values. Where does that data come from? How was it generated? Or is this raw audio data? You can't just save raw audio to a file with an mp3 extension to make it an MP3 file