# Out of memory exception for converting 40 mil records from csv stream to tab delimited text stream

Tags: c#, memorystream

I am trying to convert csv stream to a tabdelimeted text memory stream it is giving me error of out of memory exception when it is trying to write to the stream, it is getting processed in local machine but, the issue is happening on dev env after code deployment.

Below is the sample code:

```
MemoryStream tabDelimitedStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var reader = new StreamReader(downloadFileData))
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tabDelimitedStream, Encoding.UTF8 ,8096))
{
    // Read the lines from the original stream and process them
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        char[] buffer = new char[8096];
        int bytesRead;
        string chunk;
        while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            chunk = new string(buffer, 0, bytesRead).Replace(",", "\t");
            writer.Write(chunk);
            writer.Flush();
        }
    }
    tabDelimitedStream.Position = 0;
```

I am trying to read it in buffers but still it is failing, i tried to set max length of `tabDelimitedStream` that is also not solving the issue. any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

tried adding to buffers and write in chunks but no luck.

Comment: You are writing to `MemoryStream` - thus all the data you write sits in the memory.

Comment: Well, you obviously run out of memory because you push everything to MemoryStream. And therefore entire data sits in memory. Did you mean to push it outside somewhere? Like file or network?

Comment: You should try writing to a FileStream in stead of a MemoryStream. Look at this for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/411592/how-do-i-save-a-stream-to-a-file-in-c

Comment: i want it to be in a memorystream and that will be uploaded to a blob storage

Comment: i dont want to save it into a file

Comment: Note that "replacing commas with tabs" is not strictly correct handling of a CSV input.  Due to quoting, not every comma in a CSV file is a column separator.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to upload it to a blob storage, you can write directly to blob stream instead of allocating it in memory (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-upload#upload-to-a-stream-in-blob-storage)

Tip: Please give us the full context next time